# Is it possible to create a mono mdb from a .net pdb?

Tags: .net, mono, debug-symbols

Is it possible to create a mono mdb from a .net pdb?

Or do I need to build the binary with two compilers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical

"You can convert PDB files to MDB files using "pdb2mdb" in mono tree, a program written by JB Evain"

http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/04/27/pdb2mdb-and-mono-cecil-pdb

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. Much appreciated

Comment: Broken download now

Comment: Since the original download is broken: [Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/pdb2mdb), [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.pdb2mdb), [Build Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42270562/785111)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool inside Unity Editor called pdb2mdb.exe, and that can be found at

```
Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\pdb2mdb.exe
```

If you face any issue in this version then there are other versions also, check this path

```
Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5\pdb2mdb.exe
```