# Xamarin - Attach c# source code to NuGet package

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

Can't find a way to attach source code to the pre-build assemblies in my c#/mono project in xamarin ide.
I want to read the source code/implementation of some open-source NuGet assemblies(source files are available on github).
In Visual Studio there is a feature called "attach source" so you can attach source code to any pre-build assembly and read the implementation of any open-source Nuget package easily.
Is there a workaround to make it possible in Xamarin studio ?

thank you

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.  You generally have a project that has source files, and those source files can reference assemblies that are installed as part of a nuget package.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  I don't think XS supports that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View Source:**

If you have a Method/Property from a 3rd-party package highlighted in XS/MD and 'Goto to Declaration' (right-click/select, cmd-D, ...), the Assembly Viewer will open since you do not have the source. Change the dropdown in the upper right of the window from Summary to C#.

**Debugging:**

*Will Xamarin Studio will support the feature to optionally debug third library frameworks (via PDB) via 'http://www.symbolsource.org' for example?*

> June 2014 : We don't currently have any plans for this, but please
>   suggest it on UserVoice.

Note: I can not find the UserVoice discussion @  http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17934/support-for-source-server-support

Add a new one @ [Xamarin Product Suggestions](http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-product-suggestions)

**You can do this manually:**

Grab the PDBs that you need from symbolsource.org (or another symbol providing service such as Microsoft's reference source PDB, etc..) and manually convert the [PDB to MDBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102913/is-it-possible-to-create-a-mono-mdb-from-a-net-pdb)

*Personally* I have done it, but PDB to MSB via Cecil is not always(?) perfect and you have to make sure the correct version of PDBs are being used otherwise this is going to fail. At this point if I am really tracing a bug, I will just overlay the open source into my project as an submodule and configure/build/reference it...

Comment: Actually I don't need to debug the source code but only read the source and look at implementation.   Nuget is really great and it is such a shame we can't use it if we want to read the source code easily even it is open-source.  It would be awesome if I could just right-click the reference library in xamarin and "attach" the source folder just to be able to read the implementation.

Comment: Try: If you have a Method/Property from a 3rd-party package highlighted in XS/MD and cmd-D to 'Goto to Declaration', the Assembly Viewer will open since you do not have the source. Change the dropdown in the upper right of the window from Summary to C#.

Comment: I guess this should be the correct answer. Thank you )

Comment: Depend on UserVoice about Symbol Server https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/6735876-better-debug-experience-with-support-for-symbol-se